# gcc compile error: /usr/bin/ld: gfx.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, fpic

Error is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: gfx.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:4: project] Error 1
```

and when I add `-fPIC` or `-fPIE`, nothing changes. I know that the `gfx.o` library works, since it was working previously and still works when I ssh on my server.

Make file is as follows:

```
project: project.c
  gcc project.c gfx.o -lx11 -lm -fPIE -o -project
clean:
  rm project
```

I tried to use `-fPIE` and `-fPIC` in the makefile. I also treid uninstalling and reinstalling gcc and binutills, but nothing worked.

Comment: recompile with -fPIE...

Comment: I already tried that, but it still displays the same prompt.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your question.

Comment: As for your problem, you can copy-paste the actual error message into your favorite search engine, and you should be getting plenty of hits to explain why you get it and how it can be solved. Heck, if you look at the right side of this question, under the "Related" section, you will find plenty of questions about it on this site.

Comment: I did look for 2 hours for the solution for the error, but all of the fixes seemed to say to add -fPIC or -fPIE which did not work

Comment: You have added `-fPIE` to the link line where you compile `project.c` and link it in.  But the error message clearly says that the problem is with `gfx.o`, not `project.c`, and you haven't done anything in that makefile to specify that you need to build `gfx.o` with `-fPIE`.

Comment: How would I go about applying -fPIE to gfx.o when gfx.o is precompiled when I receive it?

Comment: You might ask whoever provides that file to you to be compile it with that option

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that putting `-no-pie` in the Makefile solves the issue. I don't know if there is a more permanent and widespread fix, but it works.